# Pointer in Functions from a Pointer: Declaration is incompatible

Tags: c

I habe problems with some parameters in a funktions.
The compiler say the declaration is incompatible, but i didnt see my mistake ?
The Funktions calls "output"
So the declaration is the same as the definition.

I have to add:
I use structs and varaibles, which i defined in the main function and I pass these on to the output function via pointer to two other functions.

```css
Header: 
#ifndef def_struct_H
#define def_struct_H
void output (const char * ,const struct Charakter *,struct Gegner *,int ,int);
#endif 

Funktion "Output":
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "def_DDice.h"
#include "def_data.h"

void output (const char Sitzungsname,const struct Charater* Daten,struct Gegner *NPCs,int SPC_ANZ,int NPC_ANZ) {

    time_t t = time (NULL);
    struct tm * ts;    
    ts = localtime(&t);
    
    struct sequence Initiativ_Reihenfolge [MAX_C*2];
    struct sequence temp_sort [1];
/*structs zusammen kopieren*/
    int copy;
    for (copy = 0; copy >= SPC_ANZ+NPC_ANZ; ++copy) 
    {
        if (copy < NPC_ANZ) {
            memcpy (Initiativ_Reihenfolge[copy].Teilnehmer,NPCs[copy].Name,sizeof((struct Gegner*)0)->Name);
            memcpy (Initiativ_Reihenfolge[copy].Summe,NPCs[copy].Summe,sizeof((struct Gegner*)0)->Summe);
        }
        if (copy >= NPC_ANZ && copy <= SPC_ANZ) {
            memcpy (Initiativ_Reihenfolge[copy].Teilnehmer,Daten/*[copy].Name*/,sizeof((struct Charakter*)0)->Name);

        }
        

/*Bubblesort*/
    int all_1, all_2;

    for (all_1 = 0; all_1 < MAX_C*2; ++all_1) 
    {
        for (all_2 = 0; all_2 < (MAX_C*2)-all_1; ++all_2) 
        {
            if (Initiativ_Reihenfolge[all_2].Summe > Initiativ_Reihenfolge[all_2+1].Summe)
            {
                memcpy (&temp_sort,&Initiativ_Reihenfolge[all_2],sizeof(struct sequence)); //??
                memcpy (&Initiativ_Reihenfolge[all_2],&Initiativ_Reihenfolge[all_2+1],sizeof(struct sequence));
                memcpy (&Initiativ_Reihenfolge[all_2+1],&temp_sort,sizeof(struct sequence));                      
            }
        }
    }  
}

Call in previous function:    
output (Sitzung,Daten,NPC,SPC_ANZ,NPC_ANZ);
```

Comment: I would suggest to include also a variable name in the function declaration in your header file (i.e. `int varName`). You should also double check the second function parameter. In the header file you specify a `const struct Charakter*` type, but then in the function you have `const struct Charater*`

Comment: Maybe fix some spelling errors.

Comment: Thank you a lot! 
It was just a simple spelling error, I thought I was freaking out.